# percentage height to child inside of parent element with view port height does not work

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i am giving height to parent in viewport as 90vh and height to child element as 90% but this element is not taking up this much area and shows just a line. I am confused as to the parent height,so the child must correspond to this height

```
<div className="min-h-[80vh]">
  <div className="h-[90%]">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you set `position:relative` on the parent?

Comment: and how do you know how big the elements are?  Add a border to the divs to see their size

Comment: Square brackets are used as attribute selectors in CSS so if your class names actually contain them as you've shown here then it won't work.

Comment: percentage height need height as reference not **min-height**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues preventing your code from doing what you want:

1. Class names cannot contain certain characters, like percent signs and as user 3in0 mentioned - square brackets which can be confused with the CSS attribute selector.
2. Percentage heights are based on the parent's height, but not it's min/max height, which are not factored into the calculation. I assume you are using min-height given the classname, so your 90% child height will be 90% of auto (inital/default value). Auto essentially means 'whatever height you need' - 90% of auto = auto.

```css
.min-h-80vh {
  background-color: seagreen;
  height: 80vh;
}

.h-90 {
  background-color: coral;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="min-h-80vh">
  <div class="h-90">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *so your 90% child height will be 90% of auto* --> no, it will be ignored and the percentage will behave as auto. It won't do 90% of auto

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes that's what I mean, 90% of auto = auto, I can never explain it well